# Can you remove default color schemes from vim in a vimrc?

Tags: vim

I've reduced the number of custom color schemes in vim to the bare minimum of great ones, but I still have all of the crazy defaults, like `elflord`, which I'd rather not have to tab through. Can I remove these without hacking my MacVim install and having to do it in the next update?

Obviously this is splitting hairs, but configuring my `.vimrc` in the first place is splitting hairs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tmcw,

My installation of vim73 has the colors stored in \path\to\vim\vim73\colors.

In there I see elflord.vim and a host of other files.

Presumably removing them from this directory should remove them altogether.

Then, you can just tab through whatever you want.

Edit: If you want to have something that goes in and removes the files from the colors directory after an update, perhaps you may have to write a script to manage that--I'm not really sure.

HTH

Comment: sadly this is the best answer at this point, maybe there is a way to avoid adding default colorschemes on compilation?

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are tabbing through your colorschemes for editing different filetypes? why not just set up your `colorscheme` preference in corresponding filetype-specific entries using `autocmd FileType` or via individual vim files in the `ftplugin` directory. Make sure you have `filetype plugin on`

Answer (score 0):

How many colorschemes do you actually use? If it's just a few (and you really need to change them frequently, like whether it's dark or bright daylight), I'd define shortcut commands, like:

```
command -bar Col1 colorscheme default
command -bar Col2 colorscheme darkblue
```

You could remove the colorschemes from `$VIMRUNTIME/colors/`, but you're right about having to do this after every Vim upgrade.

A (complex) alternative would be writing a custom `:Colorscheme` command, with a custom completion that uses something like a blacklist to suppress certain schemes. As a bonus, with the *cmdalias* plugin, you could even overwrite the original `:colorscheme` command, to make this fully transparent.